# React prop value is not available inside a function within child Component

Tags: reactjs, function, react-hooks, instance

Why am getting props.data as empty within child component function.

sample code is given below to explain my problem.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [state, usestate] = usestate();
  useEffect(() => {
    // async api call
    // After successfull response
    usestate(apiData);
  }, []);
  const handleClick = () => {
    //sample
  };
  return <ChildComponent handleClick={handleClick} data={state} />;
};

//ChildComponent

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  const handleClick1 = (e) => {
    // Here am getting empty value when I try props.data (this happening only for the first time)
    console.log(props.data); // empty
  };
  return <subChild handleClick={handleClick1} />;
};
```

Note : Am getting json response from api and data is available inside the child, But value is empty for the first time when I trigger handleClick(happening at this particular instance)

Parent component is also not re-rendering - verified

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that you get undefined the first time

[image: react component lifecycle]
when you do

```
const[state,usestate]= useState()
```

your variable **state** has for value undefined

the useEffect hook is called after the first rendering of your parent component, so when your parent is first rendered there is no value in your **state** yet and this empty value is passed to the child.

Comment: Thanks, I can see the api data in child component when the page is rendered. only on handleclick the prop value is missing.